# Fixing crashes Windows Phone apps with crashinfo of dev dashboard

Tags: exception, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a simple wp8.1 app published in the store ([universal app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx)) but it crashed. So I downloaded the excel file containing crash info from https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/DownloadReport
The crash(es) occur in the latest version of my app and the clients have 8.1 (because you cannot run universal apps otherwise)

Here is a small list of all problem functions and their exception type:

- mscoree!CoreCLRRunner::CoreCLRInstance::RunAssembly (APPLICATION_FAULT)
- windows_ni (STOWED_EXCEPTION_FINALIZER)
- twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::ForwardLocalError (WRONG_SYMBOLS_kernel32legacy.dll)
- windows_ui!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages (STOWED_EXCEPTION)
- bad_dump!stowed_exception_structure_invalid (STATUS_STOWED_EXCEPTION)

but I'd like to focus on the top one, because that occurred the most.
This is the top *Problem function* `mscoree!CoreCLRRunner::CoreCLRInstance::RunAssembly`
So here is the related stacktrace:

> Frame    Image             Function                                               Offset
>   0        ntdll.dll         LdrAppxHandleIntegrityFailure                          0x0000011a
>   1        ntdll.dll         LdrpFindOrMapDll                                       0x000004f6
>   2        ntdll.dll         LdrpLoadDll                                            0x00000248
>   3        ntdll.dll         LdrLoadDll                                             0x00000050
>   4        kernelbase.dll    LoadLibraryExW                                         0x00000084
>   5        CoreClr.dll       CLRLoadLibraryExWorker                                 0x0000003c
>   6        CoreClr.dll       CLRLoadLibraryEx                                       0x00000012
>   7        CoreClr.dll       LoadedImageLayout::LoadedImageLayout                   0x0000004e
>   8        CoreClr.dll       PEImageLayout::Load                                    0x0000002e
>   9        CoreClr.dll       PEImage::GetLayoutInternal                             0x00000042
>   10       CoreClr.dll       PEImage::GetLayout                                     0x000000d8
>   11       CoreClr.dll       PEImage::HasNativeHeader                               0x00000030
>   12       CoreClr.dll       BINDER_SPACE::AssemblyBinder::GetAssembly              0x00000094
>   13       CoreClr.dll       BINDER_SPACE::AssemblyBinder::BindByTpaList            0x0000024a
>   14       CoreClr.dll       BINDER_SPACE::AssemblyBinder::BindLocked               0x00000040
>   15       CoreClr.dll       BINDER_SPACE::AssemblyBinder::BindLockedOrService      0x00000030
>   16       CoreClr.dll       BINDER_SPACE::AssemblyBinder::BindWhereRef             0x000000b4
>   17       CoreClr.dll       BINDER_SPACE::AssemblyBinder::BindAssembly             0x00000150
>   18       CoreClr.dll       CLRPrivBinderCoreCLR::Bind                             0x00000060
>   19       CoreClr.dll       AssemblySpec::Bind                                     0x000001fe
>   20       CoreClr.dll       AppDomain::BindAssemblySpec                            0x00000372
>   21       CoreClr.dll       AssemblySpec::LoadDomainAssembly                       0x000000f6
>   22       CoreClr.dll       AssemblySpec::LoadAssembly                             0x00000014
>   23       CoreClr.dll       AssemblySpec::LoadAssembly                             0x00000042
>   24       CoreClr.dll       CorHost2::ExecuteAssembly                              0x00000088
>   25       MSCOREE.DLL       CoreCLRRunner::CoreCLRInstance::RunAssembly            0x00000080
>   26       MSCOREE.DLL       _lambda_0f67c82022084a65857b171f2e9c0e8b_::operator    0x000001d0
>   27       MSCOREE.DLL       _CorExeMain                                            0x0000000a
>   28       ntdll.dll         RtlUserThreadStart                                     0x00000016

and I have no idea to fix all of these 5 crashes. My wp app is so small, it should be easy to have it bug/crash free.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't always obvious what causes these. From my own experience I would highly suspect this isn't caused by your code but by either someone using a beta version of the OS or a bug in how Windows Phone handles the closing of an app.

I don't know this for sure but I've seen similar unintelligible crashes for my app and this answer was what I got when I put the question out to some other experienced WP developers.